# gdb backtrace frames with and without address

Tags: gdb

When I do gdb bt - I see some frames start with address and some not - why some functions don't start with the address

```
#6  0x000000000041fd1d in func (argc=0, argv=0x8723a0, t=<value optimized out>) at file1.c:55
#7  record (argc=0, argv=0x8723a0, x=<value optimized out>) at file3.c:11
```

Comment: Can you provide the function signature for the 'record' function? and also for the 'func' function. I want to check if they are inlined etc. Ideally when you debug the most recent stack frame always does not show the function address - http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_toc.html#TOC42 (check the last line). But in your case it seems for the last frame. I still wonder why! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `record()` is inlined and is part of another function which is an upper frame  and `func()` is not inlined. I guess it is `gdb` that chooses to show inlined functions in this way if it has symbol information. I use gdb 7.0. It seems that earlier versions of gdb does not show inlined functions in this way.

Look, I have more or less the same situation with bt:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 1405):
#0  0x00002ac752a93d17 in allocate (this=0x3716b1e0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /import/home/bc_prod1/bc/data/daily/PROF_HAS_LIBS_005.00/18.05.2012_15_19_04/i686-redhat-linux_5.0_-64/src/build/xalanc-1.11/xml-xalan/c/src/xalanc/Include/XalanList.hpp:537
#1  getListHead (this=0x3716b1e0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /import/home/bc_prod1/bc/data/daily/PROF_HAS_LIBS_005.00/18.05.2012_15_19_04/i686-redhat-linux_5.0_-64/src/build/xalanc-1.11/xml-xalan/c/src/xalanc/Include/XalanList.hpp:517
#2  end (this=0x3716b1e0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /import/home/bc_prod1/bc/data/daily/PROF_HAS_LIBS_005.00/18.05.2012_15_19_04/i686-redhat-linux_5.0_-64/src/build/xalanc-1.11/xml-xalan/c/src/xalanc/Include/XalanList.hpp:282
#3  xalanc_1_11::ICUBridgeCollationCompareFunctorImpl::~ICUBridgeCollationCompareFunctorImpl (this=0x3716b1e0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /import/home/bc_prod1/bc/data/daily/PROF_HAS_LIBS_005.00/18.05.2012_15_19_04/i686-redhat-linux_5.0_-64/src/build/xalanc-1.11/xml-xalan/c/src/xalanc/ICUBridge/ICUBridgeCollationCompareFunctorImpl.cpp:144
```

My explantion is that in my situation `getListHead()` from frame 1, `end()` from the frame 2 were inlined and that is why they are shown without own address. They are actually part of frame 3 function `ICUBridgeCollationCompareFunctorImpl::~ICUBridgeCollationCompareFunctorImpl()` which actually was not inlined and has its address.

By the way when I do `disass` for frame 1, frame 2 and frame 3 I have got the same output.